# Two keys pressed simultaneously in autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm wiring innards of a keyboard to make a board of buttons to use as macros for photoshop among other applications. The insert key and a letter key is wired to a single tactile switch. This is done with each letter switch.

I can use `Ins & a::` but because I can't predict which will be "read" first, I have to have the reverse as well. The problem is that when I use `a & Ins::` the 'a' key doesn't work properly.

Is there a way to use the 'up' and 'down' function with a letter key? Maybe that will work? Otherwise if there is a way to determine if two keys were pressed within a certain time between each other, I believe that would work.

Comment: Have you tried to restore the `a` key's original function? `a::Send, a` and maybe `+a::Send, A`. The same would apply to `Ins`.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't function naturally. The `a` key has to be pressed down and released for `a` to send. I use touch typing and sometimes the speed at which I type cancels out the `a` being pressed.

Comment: There's no way around that. Using a key combination with `&` makes the first key a *prefix key*. It can by definition only fire upon release (How else is the OS going to determine that you don't want to press `Ins` additionally?). I suggest using one or more of the original prefix keys instead, e.g. `ALT`, `CTRL` or `SHIFT`.

Answer (score 0):

Try these sentences:

```
 Ins & a::SendRaw The Ins&a thing...
 a & Ins::Send, The a&Ins thing...
 a::SendRaw, a
```

This fixes your problem with the `a` key (although now the normal `a` appears with some delay).